Avoid spaces before and after `std::cout` in listings
In this example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=c++,
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    literate={::}{{::}}2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
std::mutex mtx;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

What I get is std :: mutex mtx;. I do not want these automatic spaces in listing mode.
Is there a way to disable them?

This is a consequence of the default setting of fixed columns, i.e., every character has the same width. Because the : character is not very wide it looks like a space is introduced.
A workaround is to set the literate width of :: to 1 character, i.e., literate={::}{{::}}1. Otherwise you can use flexible or full-flexible columns. Another option would be to use a teletype font, in which case the :: characters are wider and evenly spaced so it doesn't look like extra spaces are introduced.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=single}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textit{Flexible columns:}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible]
std;;mutex mtx;
wwwwwwwwwwwwww;

std::mutex mtx;
\end{lstlisting}
\noindent \textit{Full-flexible columns:}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible]
std;;mutex mtx;
wwwwwwwwwwwwww;

std::mutex mtx;
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{
    columns=fixed,
    language=c++,
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    literate={::}{{::}}1
}
\noindent\textit{Fixed columns, :: seen as 1 character:}
\begin{lstlisting}
std;;mutex mtx;
wwwwwwwwwwwwww;

std::mutex mtx;
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{
    columns=fixed,
    language=c++,
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    literate={::}{{::}}2
}
\noindent\textit{Fixed columns, :: seen as 2 characters, teletype font:}
\begin{lstlisting}
std;;mutex mtx;
wwwwwwwwwwwwww;

std::mutex mtx;
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}

Result:

